# Google Earth Engine how to turn image collection bands into histograms

Tags: image-processing, histogram, google-earth-engine

I am trying to replicate this paper here https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-89779-z where they use satellite data to predict crop yield using machine learning. One of the steps they do is shown in this image here: [image]

The authors turn a image collection into a frequency histogram by observing all of the pixel values in a select region. How would you code this using google earth engine in google colab?